# Regex - how to match everything apart from a specific string?

Tags: regex

I have this following regex `^(.*)/news` which works for the following

- something/news
- somethingelse/news
- yougettheidea/news

However I don't want it to match

- category/news

Any idea? I've tried `^(?!category)(.*)/news` but no luck.

Comment: `^(?!category)(.*)\/news` should work fine.

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: IIS Rewrites but the regex I specified doesn't work. Tested on https://regex101.com/ and it matches

Comment: Just add a condition that it doesn't match `^category/news`.  equals with a negate if that helps.  That said `^(.*)(?<!category)/news` might work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this (`^(.*)(?<!category)/news`) might work, I would just do the following on the rule in question instead:

```
<conditions>
  <add input="{R:1}" pattern="category" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```