# Javascript RegEx to match everything up until and after a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I need a regex to match everything in a string except a sub-string of a given pattern, which may appear several times.

#### Example text:

---

*A lot of text before my pattern.*

*Perhaps several lines...*

*...then [**my pattern here**]. Then maybe [**my pattern here**] again and some more text to end.*

---

The pattern in case is anything starting with "000." and followed by however many alphanumeric characters except a space. So, for example, valid tokens would be:

- **000.a**
- **000.1a**
- **000.SomeLongWordHere!123**

Firstly, I started to match the pattern itself, which I managed to with `/000\.[^ ]+/ g`. Then I tried to negate that, with `/(?!000\.[^ ]+)/ g` and variations of that, adding things like `.+` before, before and after, but none works for what I need.

I looked into several other questions regarding regex (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810610/match-everything-except-a-specific-pattern-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574090/regex-how-to-match-everything-apart-from-a-specific-string)), but wasn't lucky (or didn't quite understand how to apply the answers to my need).

I'm using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test.

Using the above example text, the desired result is:

---

*A lot of text before my pattern.*

*Perhaps several lines...*

*...then . Then maybe  again and some more text to end.*

---

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it not a simple matter of removing the found patterns from the original input? so doing a replace (with empty string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Doqnach mentioned in the comments, it seems you just want to do a [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Using your regex:

`text.replace(/000\.[^ ]+/g, "");`

And here's a working example:

```js
let text = `A lot of text before my pattern.

Perhaps several lines...

...then 000.SomeLongWordHere!123 Then maybe 000.1a again and some more text to end.`

 // Easiest way
console.log("=== Using Replace ===\n\n");
console.log(text.replace(/000\.[^ ]+/g, ""));


// Using regex exec
console.log("\n\n=== Regex exec ===\n\n");

let regex = /(?:^|(?:000\.[^ ]+))((?:(?!000\.[^ ]+)[\S\s])*)/igm;
let content = "";
while(result = regex.exec(text)){
     //In Group 1 is the content that does not match the desired pattern
     content+= result[1]; 
}
console.log(content);
```

Second method breakdown in: https://regex101.com/r/nR9tV6/16

Comment: I understand it could be done using that approach. However, my biggest interest is to be able to retrieve everything that does **not** match the given pattern. (Also to learn more of the regex syntax)

Comment: @NickFanelli  The result of that `replace` is everything that **didn't** match the pattern...

Comment: I understand that. The _replace_ operation is like applying a negation to the pattern. It is the negation of the pattern, using regex, which I am interested in. Is it possible?

Comment: @NickFanelli there you go, it's a little harder but https://regex101.com/r/nR9tV6/16

Comment: superb! Exactly as I needed. Can you edit your answer so that I can accept it? Thank you!

Comment: @NickFanelli My answer was already updated, check  the second method. If edition is not enough let me know